# Nested forms Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a model Person and a model Option. Option belongs_to person, and Person has_many options. In the form for creating a new Person I want to be able to add several Options before you save the Person. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for rails casts episode 196 and 197  . they have detailed explation and are the best to implement this kind of functionality

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessarily the best solution, but Ryan Bates' [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) library makes managing dynamic form elements for associated models quite easy. Easy to install and the [usage directions in the README](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/README.md#usage) sound like they cover your basic case.

Answer (score 0):

You might find my question, which was answered, and for which I post more or less complete solution files for, to be of use with nested associations:

[Why submitting to wrong action when implementing "favorites", modeled after Michael Hartl's following / followers in Rails Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377949/why-submitting-to-wrong-action-when-implementing-favorites-modeled-after-mich)